# Java - read files from different maven modules

Tags: java, maven, module

I have an application consisting of three modules: Module A, Module B and Module C (which is a web module). I am using Maven to build the application.

I have the following logic implemented: Module A is included in Module B using a maven dependency and Module B is included in Module C, also by using a dependency (I have separate pom files for each module). Module C is the one that gets deployed.

In Module C I want to have a folder called files, that would contain some content files. This particular folder would be located under the webapp folder. I want to be able to read these files in Module B.

Is there a way to do this? I have tried reading files with getClass().getResourceAsStream("files/file_name") but the returned value was null.

Comment: if you want to pick up a file from the root of the classloader, use `/files/file_name` (starting slash). Ensure that this file exists in the other module: `src/main/resources/files/file_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most clean solution:

- Create a new module `D`.
- Put the files into `D/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/`
- Add `D` as a dependency to `B`

That makes the files available to `B` as resource on the classpath while keeping them mostly separate from everything else. Note that to get the files, you have to use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/...");
```

otherwise Java will try to load them relative to the current class.

Be careful that you don't have file in `C` and `D` with the same names. If you do, then it can be somewhat random which file Java will pick.

Comment: I see your point. The file names won't be a problem as Module C will only contain config files in the WEB-INF folder. I think I'll go with this one, as it is indeed the cleaner solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to put all these files into `/src/main/resources` directory in order to allow these files being in the application classpath when it is deployed. So, you can consider from your B module that all those files are available in the classpath.

Obviously, you have to take in consideration to copy those files in the `/src/main/resources` module B's directory.